# Unable to start XAMPP properly

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell, xampp

I am facing the below issue while starting the xampp on linux box.
I am able to start the mysql and proFPD but i couldn't satrt the apache.
It showing another webserver is already running.

**XAMPP**: Starting Apache fail.
**XAMPP**: Another web server is already running.
**XAMPP**: Starting MySQL already running.
**XAMPP**: Starting ProFTPD already running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have httpd daemon running already.

Go to terminal and type `service httpd stop`

Then try starting XAMPP

Comment: I am getting :

Stopping httpd: [FAILED]

Comment: what use are you logged in as? you might need to use sudo

Comment: i am logged in as root user...i used 

( sudo service httpd stop ) but still it doesn't working.

Comment: @lakhan try this `service httpd status` - that will tell you if httpd is running

Comment: Yes i did used this but i am getting httpd is stopped

and /opt/lampp/lampp start

Comment: i did i get this httpd is stopped. 

And XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.

Answer (score 1):

```
- if you start lampp and are fetching apache starting issue run below
   command

    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop && sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```